# Codeblocks ld.exe image error with png extensions. 2D graphics in codeblocks

Tags: codeblocks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX2lF.png)[Errors are shown in the image[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUtly.png)I've added files in the code block project directory.

```
>>>>Texture t1,t2,t3;
    t1.loadFromFile("background.png");
    t2.loadFromFile("car.png");
    t1.setSmooth(true);
    t2.setSmooth(true);

    Sprite sBackground(t1), sCar(t2);
    sBackground.scale(2,2);
```

background and car pngs could not be loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the .depend and .png files from your project, as these are not source files.